# SAP Spartacus - Intercept and handle HTTP error

Tags: angular, spartacus-storefront

I am trying to handle the error response of a request as described in the official documentation: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/http-error-handling/ but my `handleError(...)` method is never called. It does not show any error in the console (or hinting any other clue).

What I did so far:

1. Created a new handler `SomeRandomErrorHandler` which extends the out-of-the-box `HttpErrorHandler` from Spartacus like so:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SomeRandomErrorHandler extends HttpErrorHandler {

   handleError(_request: HttpRequest<any>, response: HttpErrorResponse): void {
    console.log('SHOW ME SOMETHING. "handleError" class called.');
    this.getErrors(response).forEach(({ message }: ErrorModel) => {
      console.log('Print the message from the response: ', message);
    });
  }

  protected getErrors(response: HttpErrorResponse): ErrorModel[] {
    return (response.error?.errors || []).filter(
      (error) =>
        error.type === 'SomeRandomException'
    );
  }

  getPriority(): Priority {
    return Priority.HIGH;
  }
}
```

2. Registered the new handler in `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    (...)
    SpartacusModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HttpErrorHandler,
      useExisting: SomeRandomErrorHandler,
      multi: true,
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And I still cannot see any of the console logs from the `handleError(...)` method. What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe it is a problem, that you added the HttpErrorHandler on your root Module and have defined it to be `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root',})`

Answer (score 2):

You need to **call** **super**() inside your custom handler with **globalMessageService** instance as well as **add** **responseStatus** property

```
  responseStatus = HttpResponseStatus.FORBIDDEN;

  constructor(
    private _globalMessageService: GlobalMessageService
  ) {
    super(_globalMessageService);
  }
```